# Subroutine usable in both 1D and 2D geometry

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I want to write a subroutine which could be used in 1D or 2D geometry.
Consequently I have variables that will be used only in the latter case.

I wish I could write a declaration section in that style:

```
real ( kind = double ) :: uleft,vleft,uright,vright
real ( kind = double ) :: distanceinx
real ( kind = double ) :: ...
if (ndim == 2) then
  real ( kind = double ) :: ulow,vlow,uup,vup
  real ( kind = double ) :: distanceiny
end if
```

but it doesn't compile.

Is there a syntax to do what I want to do in a proper way ?
A big part of the code will be similar in the two cases (ndim = 1 or 2) so I think that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just leave the variables there and don't use them in 1D. The syntax you propose does not exist and I don't know of any other similar one.

In Fortran 2003 you can also make them allocatable, but that is worth it only for arrays, to save some space.

Do not care about couple of unused bytes on the stack. They can remain unused in 1D.

Answer (score 2):

You could treat the 1D array as a special two-dimensional array with `Nx1`. Then you could always use the 2D version of your code. You can still check for the length of the second dimension to determine the dimension. This even allows for extension to the third dimension!

Routines/functions like `norm2` also work on both types, so this could further simplify your code.